# Puppet/Hiera: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `empty_answer' for Hiera::Backend:Module

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, hiera

I had a puppet master running for quite some time. After a restart of the process recently, I started getting:

```
    # puppet agent -t
    info: Retrieving plugin
    info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/mountpoints.rb
    info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
    info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
    info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/disks.rb
    info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
    info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
    err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `empty_answer' for Hiera::Backend:Module at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/sshauthkeys/manifests/helper.pp:2
```

If I run

```
    hiera -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml <key>
```

it works as expected. Any idea what this could be?

I'm running puppet 2.7, hiera 1.2.1 and hiera-puppet 1.0.0

Kind regards,

Kristian

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch somewhere.

Comment: That was my first assumption as well, but I can't find any issues. Let me know if I should post other things